# Only the main div to be with hidden overflow

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I am new to CSS and at the moment I am trying to learn more about it. My idea was to create one of those "One Page" websites. I created a main container with hidden overflow. However, I want to create more divs inside the main container which can be scrollable. At the bottom I will give a running sample of the code I written.

If someone could help me or at least give me some suggestions how to fix this problem I will be really grateful.

Thank you in advance.

```js
var PageOne = $(".PageOne").offset().top;
var PageTwo = $(".PageTwo").offset().top;

$(".Link1").click(function() {
    $('.Container').animate({
        scrollTop: PageOne},
        'slow');
});

$(".Link2").click(function() {
    $('.Container').animate({
        scrollTop: PageTwo},
        'slow');
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.Nav{
  position:relative;
  width:10%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:red;
  float:left;
}

.Link1, .Link2{
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:2vw;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:3vw;
  text-align:center;
}

.Container{
  position:relative;
  width:90%;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:green;
  float:left;
}

.PageOne{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:gold;
}

.PageTwo{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  min-height:100vh;
  background-color:purple;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Nav">
  <div class="Link1">
    Page 1
  </div>
  <div class="Link2">
    Page 2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Container">
  <div class="PageOne">
    Page One
  </div>
  <div class="PageTwo">
    Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>Page Two<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? What is the result you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. My idea was to create a main div which is with hidden overflow. Then allow the divs inside the main div to have a scrollable content in them. 

PS: I already fixed it. However, thank you for your reply. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do here. I have done something similar using html, css, and javascript however instead of using a container I simply made an accordion using the code below.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script>
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
  collapsible: true,
  active: false,
  heightStyle: "content"
  });
});
</script>

<div id="accordion"> 
  <h2>Heading atop accordion</h2>  
  <div>
     <p>page info inside of div</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This gives a very similar effect. However if you plan on making the page inside the container scrollable, try tweaking the dimensions of your div for page two. You can do this by extending the height of the div. Usually this can be done in html `<div style="height:500px;"></div>`. Additionally you may also be able to format the height of your page two in CSS.

There are also way to make you pages scrollable seen on this website [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_frame_scrolling.asp)

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the problem with giving the div normal height instead of minimum height.

PS: Thank you for your reply. I appreciate it.